# What's going on with the OSIRIS-REx sample caption video that's circulating on twitter?

Tags: imaging, osiris-rex

Nasa footage is available here: https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/13744

The first series ("Movie 1") shows a lower frame rate followed by what seems like a continuous, rapid collection of images. In this "movie", it seems like OSIRIS-REx TAGs Bennu very briefly--<1 second. Yet, I've heard it was a 6-second contact. This first movie has been circulated all around twitter.

This leads me to a host of questions: Is the framerate irregular or otherwise varying? Is this part of the movie "smoothed" out by generating frames between actually captured frames? What would this look like in real time?

But my real question is: **At what frame rate did OSIRIS-REx's Samcam capture images during the touch-and-go sample collection on October 20, 2020**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [press release](https://www.asteroidmission.org/?latest-news=osiris-rex-tags-asteroid-bennu) on the official website for OSIRIS-REx,

> These images were captured over approximately a five-minute period. The imaging sequence begins at about 82 feet (25 meters) above the surface, and runs through the back-away maneuver, with the last image in the sequence taken at approximately 43 feet (13 meters) in altitude – about 35 seconds after backing away. The sequence was created using 82 SamCam images, with **1.25 seconds between frames**. For context, the images are oriented with Bennu’s west at the top.

"Movie 1" is at a constant frame rate, but dramatically sped up.

That page also contains two shorter, slower clips of the sequence.